# Why the register page get autofilled with phpmyadmin id and password when the page is loaded

Tags: php, codeigniter

So, whenever I load register page, on the input field, the username and password field get autofilled with my phpmyadmin id and password (which is root and 1234)

[image: The picture of it]

So, here is the Controller user.php

```
 <?php
class User extends CI_Controller {
  public function register() {
    // load View
    $data['main_content'] = 'register';
    $this->load->view('layouts/main', $data);
  }
}
 ?>
```

Here is the main.php in folder views/layouts

```
 <?php $data['main_content'] = $main_content; ?>
<?php $this->load->view('layouts/includes/header', $data); ?>
    <!-- Display Main Content -->
    <?php $this->load->view($main_content); ?>
<?php $this->load->view('layouts/includes/footer'); ?>
```

And here is the Views register.php

```
<div class="container-fluid category-home-text">
   <h3 class="text-center text-uppercase">Register</h3>
 </div>
 <div class="container-fluid login-container">
   <form id="form1" name="form1" method="post">
     <div class="register-block">
     <div class="form-group">
      <label>Name*</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="fullname" placeholder="Enter Your Full Name">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label>Email Address*</label>
      <input type="email" class="form-control" name="email" placeholder="Enter Your Email Address">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label>Chose Username*</label>
      <input type="text" class="form-control" name="username" placeholder="Create A Username">
     </div>
     <div class="form-group">
      <label>Password*</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" placeholder="Enter A Password">
     </div>
       <div class="form-group">
      <label>Confirm Password*</label>
      <input type="password" class="form-control" name="cpassword" placeholder="Enter Password Again">
     </div>
       <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Register</button>
      </div>
    </form>
 </div>
```

I dont understand because I don't set a value on the view at all.

Comment: This has nothing to do with your view, this is simply the browser’s password manager at work …

Comment: It's the browser's behaviour. Credentials are saved by domain. So when you logged to phpmyadmin, you told your browser to remember it. So now when it detects a login form, it autofills it.

Comment: And, please change your database credentials.. using root/root is not a good idea. :)

Comment: So what is the solution then? my id password is root 1234

Comment: Either don't tell your browser to remember your password, or you could disable autocomplete i think? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2530/how-do-you-disable-browser-autocomplete-on-web-form-field-input-tag

Comment: _“So what is the solution then?”_ - to what actual _problem_? You not knowing how your browser’s password manager works? Go read up on that then ...

Comment: Alright, then. Thank you though, It works well on Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

Well, it´s really a behavior of many browsers.

What you can do is clean your browser cookies and a thing that would be
cool using is this html5 code at your inputs, but it´s useless in preventing
anyone to save the password on browser again. It´s just to don´t give "clues"
of your login.

```
(autocomplete="off")

<input type="text" autocomplete="off" class="form-control" name="fullname" placeholder="Enter Your Full Name">
```